# Javascript : How group and sum values from multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

[image]

I would like to group and get the sum of each repetition like this:

- AGE270: 9
- AGE203: 5
- AGE208: 9
- ...
- AGEXXX: n

Answer (score 13):

Simple solution using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function:

```js
// Replace arr with your actual array!
var arr = [
        { AGENDADOR: 'AGE270', TOTAL : 6},
        { AGENDADOR: 'AGE270', TOTAL : 3},
        { AGENDADOR: 'AGE203', TOTAL : 5},
        { AGENDADOR: 'AGE028', TOTAL : 9},
    ],
  
  totals = arr.reduce(function (r, o) {
    (r[o.AGENDADOR])? r[o.AGENDADOR] += o.TOTAL : r[o.AGENDADOR] = o.TOTAL;
    return r;
  }, {});

console.log(totals);
```

> `arr.reduce(callback, [initialValue])`
>
> ***initialValue***
>
> ```
> Optional. Value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback.
> ```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly, however, what is this "{}" for in the end? I did a test without and of course the result was not as expected.

Comment: @MagnoAlberto, it's called *initialValue*. I've cited from documentation as explanation

Comment: The thing is that you ended with a different object, not the same as the original but grouped.

Answer (score 0):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com):

```
var data; // the data represented by your screenshot

var counts = _.chain(data)
    .groupBy('AGENDADOR')
    .map(_.size)
    .value();
```

`counts` will now be an object like this:

```
{
    "AGE270": 9,
    "AGE203": 5,
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = {};

yourArray.forEach(function(item) {
  if(sum[item.AGENDADOR] === undefined) {
    sum[item.AGENDADOR] = 0;
  }

  sum[item.AGENDADOR] += item.TOTAL  
});
```

With this code, you'll have the total corresponding to each key in the  `sum` object. Something like this:

```
{
  AGE270: 9,
  AGE203: 5,
  AGE208: 9
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
function( data ){
        var outputObj = {} ;
        for(var i=0;i < data.length; i++){
                 datum = data[i];
                 if(outputObj[datum.AGENDADOR])
                         outputObj[datum.AGENDADOR] += parseInt( datum.TOTAL) ;
                 else
                         outputObj[datum.AGENDADOR] = parseInt( datum.TOTAL);
                }

        return outputObj;
```

};

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple map() function? Like this:

```
var t = YourArray;
var u = t.map(function (a, i) { var g = {}; g[a.AGENDADOR] = a.TOTAL; return g; });
```

Comment: Thanks, But it did not work, I thought I'd get with "map", of course, that your code was better than mine.

Comment: Have a look at Romans answer, reduce should work very good as well.